# HTML/JavaScript - How to change a value onClick of an image map

Tags: javascript, html, forms, imagemap

I'm looking to have 'answer5' change to finland, iceland, norway, sweden when the user clicks on said country's flag. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here but I believe it's somewhere within the image map. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A quiz page with questions relating to 
    SSH (Secure Shell) technology" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kai Longmore" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/style.css' />
    <title>SSH Research Project - SSH Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>SSH (Secure Shell) </h1>
        <h2>A Research Project by Kai Longmore</h2>
        <h3>SSH Quiz</h3>
     <br/>
    </header>
   <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="topic.html">About SSH</a>
    <a href="quiz.html" class="active" href="#SSH Quiz">SSH Quiz</a>
    <a href="enhancements.html">Enhancements</a>
    </nav>
    <br/>
    <form name="sshQuiz" id="sshQuiz" method="post" 
    action="http://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Student Details</legend>
            <p><label for="firstName">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" 
                 placeholder="First" maxlength="25" required="required" 
                 pattern="^[A-Za-z -]+$" title="Please use only 
                 letters/hyphens/spaces."/>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" 
            placeholder="Last" maxlength="25" required="required" 
            pattern="^[A-Za-z -]+$" title="Please use only 
            letters/hyphens/spaces."/></p>
        <p><label for="studentID">Student ID: </label>
            <input type="text" name="studentID" id="studentID" 
            placeholder="e.g. s123456789" required="required" pattern=" 
            (\w{1}\d{6}(\d{3})?)" title="Please enter either 7 or 10 
            characters, beginning with the letter 's'."/></p>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Question 1</legend>
            <p><label for="answer1">In what year was the SSH-1 protocol 
            released?</label><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer1" pattern="[0-9] 
            {1,4}" placeholder="e.g. 2018" required="required" title="Please 
            enter a year with up to 4 digits."/></p>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Question 2</legend>
            <p><label for="answer2">Who developed the SSH-1 protocol? 
            </label><br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="wuXian" 
            required="required"/> Wu Xian<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="mohammadHaddad"/> 
            Mohammad Haddad<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="tatuYlonen"/> Tatu 
            Ylönen<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="fredrikJohannsen"/> 
            Fredrik Jöhannsen</p>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Question 3</legend>
            <p><label for="answer3_1">Select as many SSH <em>protocols</em> 
            as you see.</label><br/><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_1" value="ssh2"/> SSH- 
                2<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_2" value="openBSD"/> 
                OpenBSD<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_3" value="ssh1"/> SSH- 
                1<br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer3_4" value="openSSH"/> 
                OpenSSH</p>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Question 4</legend>
            <p><label for="answer4">SSH is an: </label><br/><br/>
                <select name="answer4" form="sshQuiz" required="required">
                    <option value="">Please select...</option>
                    <option value="applicationLayer">Application layer 
                    protocol</option>
                    <option value="transportLayer">Transport layer 
                    protocol</option>
                    <option value="internetLayer">Internet layer 
                    protocol</option>
                    <option value="linkLayer">Link layer protocol</option>
                </select>
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Question 5</legend>
            <p><label for="answer5">Click on the flag of the country where 
            the SSH-1 protocol was first developed.</label>
                <input type="text" name="answer5" id="answer5" value="">
                <img src="images/flags.jpg" width="400" height="400" 
                alt="Scandinavian flags" usemap="#flagsMap">
                <map name="flagsMap" form="sshQuiz" required="required">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,200" alt="Finland" 
                    nohref 
                    onClick="document.forms[sshQuiz].answer5='finland',">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,400,200" alt="Iceland" 
                    nohref 
                    onClick="document.forms[sshQuiz].answer5='iceland',">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="0,200,200,400" alt="Norway" 
                    nohref 
                    onClick="document.forms[sshQuiz].answer5='norway',">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="200,200,400,400" alt="Sweden" 
                    nohref 
                    onClick="document.forms[sshQuiz].answer5='sweden',">
        </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit">
        </fieldset>
```

Just to be clear, I don't want to select an option AND submit with the click on the image map, just change the value so that when I press submit it posts to the php file.

Comment: Also, I apologise for any dodgy formatting, stackoverflow doesn't seem to like it when I paste from Atom.

Comment: `document.forms[sshQuiz].answer5.value = 'finland'`  <-- `.value`

Comment: That doesn't work either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You've not enclosed the form name in quotes, and you need to update the `value` attribute (you're trying to update the element itself, not its value).  There was also an odd comma after you try to set the value, which would definitely have thrown an error.  (Check the console for errors when things don't work).

Try this...

```
<map name="flagsMap" form="sshQuiz" required="required">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,200" alt="Finland" nohref 
        onClick="document.forms['sshQuiz'].answer5.value='finland'">
    <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,400,200" alt="Iceland" nohref 
        onClick="document.forms['sshQuiz'].answer5.value='iceland'">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,200,200,400" alt="Norway" nohref 
        onClick="document.forms['sshQuiz'].answer5.value='norway'">
    <area shape="rect" coords="200,200,400,400" alt="Sweden" nohref 
        onClick="document.forms['sshQuiz'].answer5.value='sweden'">
</map>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. I thought I may have just been doing something silly, I'm glad you found it. Time for another coffee for me :)

Comment: No worries - the easy ones are often the hardest to spot :)